# How to delete old linux partition with ESXI?

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, format

I'm stuck with my ESXI deployment and I have no idea how to move forward with this.  I have one of my server with Software Raid that used to be partitioned in Linux 6.2. 2 Sata drives partition in Raid 10 using Linux.  Now I have ESXI 5.1 installed on a USB drive. When I tried to create the datastore from Vsphere client, it gave me this error..

```
Call "HostDatastoreSystem.QueryVmfsDatastoreCreateOptions" for object "ha-datastoresystem" on ESXi "192.168.1.65" failed.
```

For the live of me I couldn't figure out how to format or prepare the data so that I can have esxi recognize it and enable me to create the Data Store.

Here is my fdisk -l

**fdisk –l**

```
  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653p1   *           1          26      204800  fd Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653p2              26         679     5242880  fd Linux raid autodetect
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary
/dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653p3             679        7206    52428800  fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653p4            7206      121602   918884352   5 Extended
/dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653p5            7206       11122    31457280  fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653p6           11123      121602   887424000  fd Linux raid autodetect
```

**partedUtil showGuids**

```
 Partition Type       GUID
 vmfs                 AA31E02A400F11DB9590000C2911D1B8
 vmkDiagnostic        9D27538040AD11DBBF97000C2911D1B8
 vsan                 381CFCCC728811E092EE000C2911D0B2
 VMware Reserved      9198EFFC31C011DB8F78000C2911D1B8
 Basic Data           EBD0A0A2B9E5443387C068B6B72699C7
 Linux Swap           0657FD6DA4AB43C484E50933C84B4F4F
 Linux Lvm            E6D6D379F50744C2A23C238F2A3DF928
 Linux Raid           A19D880F05FC4D3BA006743F0F84911E
 Efi System           C12A7328F81F11D2BA4B00A0C93EC93B
 Microsoft Reserved   E3C9E3160B5C4DB8817DF92DF00215AE
 Unused Entry         00000000000000000000000000000000
```

**esxcli storage core path list**

```
usb.vmhba32-usb.0:0-mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0
   UID: usb.vmhba32-usb.0:0-mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0
   Runtime Name: vmhba32:C0:T0:L0
   Device: mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0
   Device Display Name: Local USB Direct-Access (mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0)
   Adapter: vmhba32
   Channel: 0
   Target: 0
   LUN: 0
   Plugin: NMP
   State: active
   Transport: usb
   Adapter Identifier: usb.vmhba32
   Target Identifier: usb.0:0
   Adapter Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed
   Target Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed
   Maximum IO Size: 122880

sata.vmhba34-sata.0:0-t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288
   UID: sata.vmhba34-sata.0:0-t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288
   Runtime Name: vmhba34:C0:T0:L0
   Device: t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288
   Device Display Name: Local ATA Disk (t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288)
   Adapter: vmhba34
   Channel: 0
   Target: 0
   LUN: 0
   Plugin: NMP
   State: active
   Transport: sata
   Adapter Identifier: sata.vmhba34
   Target Identifier: sata.0:0
   Adapter Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed
   Target Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed
   Maximum IO Size: 33553920

sata.vmhba1-sata.0:0-t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653
   UID: sata.vmhba1-sata.0:0-t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653
   Runtime Name: vmhba1:C0:T0:L0
   Device: t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653
   Device Display Name: Local ATA Disk (t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653)
   Adapter: vmhba1
   Channel: 0
   Target: 0
   LUN: 0
   Plugin: NMP
   State: active
   Transport: sata
   Adapter Identifier: sata.vmhba1
   Target Identifier: sata.0:0
   Adapter Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed
   Target Transport Details: Unavailable or path is unclaimed
   Maximum IO Size: 33553920
```

**ls -alh /vmfs/devices/disks**

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         512 Sep 18 05:38 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         512 Sep 18 05:38 ..
-rw-------    1 root     root        1.9G Sep 18 05:38 mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0
-rw-------    1 root     root        4.0M Sep 18 05:38 mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:1
-rw-------    1 root     root      250.0M Sep 18 05:38 mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:5
-rw-------    1 root     root      250.0M Sep 18 05:38 mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:6
-rw-------    1 root     root      110.0M Sep 18 05:38 mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:7
-rw-------    1 root     root      286.0M Sep 18 05:38 mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:8
-rw-------    1 root     root      931.5G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653
-rw-------    1 root     root      200.0M Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:1
-rw-------    1 root     root        5.0G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:2
-rw-------    1 root     root       50.0G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:3
-rw-------    1 root     root      876.3G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:4
-rw-------    1 root     root       30.0G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:5
-rw-------    1 root     root      846.3G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:6
-rw-------    1 root     root      931.5G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288
-rw-------    1 root     root      200.0M Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:1
-rw-------    1 root     root        5.0G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:2
-rw-------    1 root     root       50.0G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:3
-rw-------    1 root     root      876.3G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:4
-rw-------    1 root     root       30.0G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:5
-rw-------    1 root     root      846.3G Sep 18 05:38 t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          20 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30 -> mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          22 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:1 -> mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          22 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:5 -> mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:5
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          22 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:6 -> mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          22 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:7 -> mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          22 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:8 -> mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:8
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          74 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:1 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:2 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:3 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:4 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:4
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:5 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:5
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:6 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          74 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:1 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:2 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:3 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:4 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:4
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:5 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:5
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root          76 Sep 18 05:38 vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:6 -> t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:6
```

Please help?  I'm running out of hair to pull....  :-)  Many thanks everyone.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the format @Michael.  Makes it easier to read now.  My bad.  :-(

Comment: Do you want to keep the original partitions and to resize them or do you intend to create VMFS filesystems over whole disk and to purge old data?

Comment: Thanks @dsumsky.  The ESXI is installed on USB jump drive so all I wanted was to just delete everything in the hard drive and use available space for the DataStorage.

Comment: @LeDude You **DO** understand that you won't be able to have RAID in the configuration you're pursuing, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List partitions with the command:

```
partedUtil getptbl "/vmfs/devices/disks/DeviceName"
```

Example output:

```
1 63      2249099   131 128
2 2249100 2474009   252 0
3 2474010 286487144 5   0
5 2474073 286487144 251 0
| |       |         |   |
| |       |         |   \--- attribute
| |       |         \------- type
| |       \----------------- ending sector
| \------------------------- starting sector
\--------------------------- partition number
```

Partition types:

```
Linux - 0x83 = 131
Linux SWAP - 0x82 = 130
Linux LVM - 0x8e = 142
Linux RAID - 0xfd = 253
```

Delete partition:

```
partedUtil delete "/vmfs/devices/disks/DeviceName" [partition number]
```

Comment: Thanks @GioMac.  Very nice details especially the example output.  Very clear.  The last part (delete partition) pretty much answer my question.  I'll post the details once I have the chance.

Answer (score 2):

Create an msdos partition:

```
partedUtil setptbl /vmfs/devices/disks/{id} msdos
```

See: http://www.vbrain.info/2014/04/23/cannot-format-harddisk-with-vmfs5-after-removing-it-from-raid-array/

Comment: This worked perfectly for me with a drive from an Intel Matrix array when all other methods failed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go through the VMware knowledge base article  [Manually creating a VMFS volume using vmkfstools -C](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1009829) as well as it describes required procedure in more detail (basically, what GioMac sent). In general, their knowledge base is very worth source of information and it helped me many times.

Comment: Thanks @dsumsky.  I've read all the Vmware documentation before and they can be pretty confusing thus I went to the youtube route to see how it's being done.

Answer (score 0):

All.

Here’s the step by step on how I did it.  The thing we can do with youtube nowadays ey?  Thought I posted here just to share with everyone who may have to face this problem since I can't seem to find the answer when I Google it myself.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDjzI3OOdOw

**ls /dev/disks**

```
mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0
mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:1
mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:5
mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:6
mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:7
mpx.vmhba32:C0:T0:L0:8
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:1
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:2
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:3
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:4
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:5
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:6
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:1
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:2
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:3
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:4
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:5
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:6
vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30
vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:1
vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:5
vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:6
vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:7
vml.0000000000766d68626133323a303a30:8
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:1
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:2
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:3
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:4
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:5
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574341545236353736323838574443205744:6
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:1
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:2
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:3
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:4
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:5
vml.0100000000202020202057442d574d41545638383631363533574443205744:6
```

**First Drive.**

```
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:1
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:2
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:3
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:4
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:5
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653:6

partedUtil delete /dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653 1

partedUtil delete /dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653 2

partedUtil delete /dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653 3

partedUtil delete /dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD1001FALS2D00E8B0________________________WD2DWMATV8861653 4
```

**For some reason can’t delete 5 and 6 but it disappeared after the 4th anyway.**

**Second Drive.**

```
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:1
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:2
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:3
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:4
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:5
t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288:6

partedUtil delete   /dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288 1
partedUtil delete /dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288 2

partedUtil delete /dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288 3

partedUtil delete /dev/disks/t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EALX2D009BA0__________________________WD2DWCATR6576288 4
```